# Inserting an Element into an array while moving items to the right

Tags: java, arrays

So let's say I have an array: `{5, 7, 8, 9, 10}`. However, I want to insert an element so that the array becomes `{5, 6, 7, 8, 9}` inserting `6` between `5` and `7`, moving `10` out and shifting `9` to the right.

How do I use arrays and for loops to solve this problem?

Comment: Don't use a for loop.  Use `System.arraycopy` [docs here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy-java.lang.Object-int-java.lang.Object-int-int-).  This is what it's for.

Answer (score 2):

arrays are extremely low-level constructs that do not have methods that do this for you. `ArrayList` does which should be used for such a job.

If, as purely an academic exercise which should never make it to production, you are intrigued as to how the authors of ArrayList make such a thing:

By.. just.. doing it.

Break down the steps and perform them all.

```
Starting state: [5, 7, 8, 9, 10]
 Desired state: [5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ]
```

In other words, We need to copy 7/8/9 into new positions to make room. Once that is done, we can write the 6.

```
int[] in = {5, 7, 8, 9, 10};
// Copy starting from index 1 (second number)
// Copy into the same array, at index 2.
// ... and copy 3 numbers.
System.arraycopy(in, 1, in, 2, 3);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(in));
// Prints: [5, 7, 7, 8, 9].
in[1] = 6;
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(in));
// Prints: [5, 6, 7, 8, 9].
```